# PDO prepare statement parameters

Tags: pdo, prepared-statement

I just started to learn PDO and i read that in prepare statements you can use named parameters and question marks parameter. So which should i use, or they are completely the same and is just the matter of my decision which to use? Becuase i saw more people choose to use question mark parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, question marks produce dramatically shorter code.
Being not a novelist  but programmer, I prefer concise code like this

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE name=? and pass=?");
$stm->execute(array($name,$pass));
$id  = $stm->fetchColumn();
```

while named placeholders will require me to write every name a dozen times.

But anyway, it's indeed only a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, but using "named parameters" is (for obvious reasons) a lot easier, and more clear. 
A good thing about named parameters is that you can see in your code what variable is inserted where in the query, and adding pieces of code (later on) is easier because everything has a name and is not depended on the order of the parameters.

Comment: thank you :) i saw many programmers using question mark parameters but personally i use named parameters and i thought it may be not so secure or smthing.